# How does Dll Plugin work with Webpack2?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, dllplugin, dllreferenceplugin

I'm updating our app to webpack2, and with webpack1, we used the Dll plugin, but I'm not sure if the plugin is still necessary with webpack2, or if any changes need to be made. 
To clarify, we were defining the DllPlugin in the webpack-vendor config file and defining the DllReferencePlugin in the main webpack config file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert, but we have the same situation. I didn't see why we still need it, `webpack 2`, its splitting our code to: `base code` and `3rd party dependencies` without any extra plugins.

In the `webpack.config.js`
like:

```
entry: {
     js: 'app.js',
     vendor: ['react', 'mobx' ,mobx-react']
}
```

Also I have the same question and didn't found any documentation.

Hope it helps

Comment: we want it so that we dont have to reload our vendor files every time time we run webpack. we have a separate webpack config for our webpack files. it speeds up our main webpack by a lot